# beginner java - printing tables

Tags: java, arrays

I'm printing values from 0-99 and a random string from food array. I can't seem to output them to a table correctly.

```
String foods[] = {"Bread", "Pizza", "Cheese"};
for (int x = 0; x<=99; x++) {
      for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
          int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
          System.out.print(x + " - " + foods[random] + "\t\t");
      }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Actual Output:

```
0 - Pizza      0 - Bread     0 - Cheese    0 - Bread
1 - Bread      1 - Pizza     1 - Bread     1 - Pizza
.... until 99
```

Expected Output:

```
0 - Pizza      1 - Bread     2 - Cheese    3 - Bread
4 - Bread      5 - Pizza     6 - Bread     7 - Pizza
.... until 99
```

Comment: What would be the output you're looking for then?

Comment: In a different note: try to be consistent in all your code. In this case, inside a for statement use always '<' or '<=' but don't mix it up, will help you in the future, improving readability when doing more complex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are incrementing x only after the inner for runs and print an entire line.

```
String foods[] = {"Bread", "Pizza", "Cheese"};
    for (int x = 0; x <= 99; ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            System.out.print(x + " - " + foods[random] + "\t\t");
             x++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

You must increment x inside the inner for.

Answer (score 2):

this will do the job :

```
    String foods[] = {"Bread", "Pizza", "Cheese"};
    for (int x = 1; x<=100; x++) {

              int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
              System.out.print((x-1) + " - " + foods[random] + "\t\t");
              if(x%4==0)
                  System.out.println();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Try this code**

```
import java.io.*;
class dev
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   String foods[] = {"Bread", "Pizza", "Cheese"};
        for (int x = 0; x<=99; x++) 
          {
             System.out.print(x + "  -" + foods[ (int) (Math.random() * 3)] + " \t\t");
              if(x%4==0) System.out.println();
           }
 }}
```